# is_plugin_active() not properly returning true

Tags: functions, activation

I have a plugin activated and working, and I installed and activated another plugin I wrote to communicate with it. However when I run is_plugin_active() I get false returned - does anyone have any idea why and how to rectify it?

EDIT: some basic code. I am in the admin area, and I'm trying to use the functions of the other plugin ultimately. But the initial check is quite basic:

```
if (is_plugin_active('Plugin2')) {
    echo 'Thanks for installing Plugin2';
} else {
    echo 'Please install Plugin2';
}
```

EDIT2: Per the codex, you do NOT need the filepath if you're using in the admin side. But  I tried with the full path, as modified here, which also did not work.

```
if (is_plugin_active('Plugin2/Plugin2.php')) {
    echo 'Thanks for installing Plugin2';
} else {
    echo 'Please install Plugin2';
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code or give some context as to how/where you are using it?

Comment: Is this example code the actual code you're using?  Because if it is, then your code won't work ... as cale_b answered below, you need the plugin directory and file name (with `.php` extension) for this to work correctly.

Comment: Is **`Plugin2`** the *actual slug* of the Plugin, or is it an "example" Plugin slug? Also: in what directory is `Plugin2` installed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I just checked for a class I knew the plugin to have, using class_exists..

Answer (score 3):

Per the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active), you need to be sure you are passing the directory and file:

```
<?php
   If (is_plugin_active('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php')) {
     //plugin is activated
  }
?>
```

Comment: Not working, and I'm the admin area anyway so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Per your  question above, it doesn't appear you are passing the file name....